# modificar el enmarcado de seleccion de input en html

Tags: html, css

tengo un input al cual le aplico un estilo de border-radius

```
border-radius: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
```

pero cuando le selecciono el marco sigue siendo rectangulo, lo muestro en una imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero que ese marco tambien sea curveado, se puede?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esa línea se la puedes quitar deshabilitando la propiedad `outline`.

Al primero de los `inputs` le he quitado el outline mientras que el segundo lo he dejado por defecto.

Ejemplo:

```css
#texto{
  outline: none;
}

.texto{
   border-radius: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="texto" value="SinOutline" class="texto">
  <input value="ConOutline" class="texto">
</form>
```

Si lo que quisieras es que apareciera una linea alrededor del borde similar a la que se muestra con la propiedad `outline`, podrías simular un `outline` usando la propiedad `box-shadow` en su defecto.

Ejemplo:

```css
#texto{
   outline: none;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px red;
}

.texto{
   border-radius: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input id="texto" value="SinOutline" class="texto">
    <input value="ConOutline" class="texto">
</form>
```

Comment: seria la unica forma eliminandolo?

Comment: @rn3w He editado mi respuesta simulando un outline.

Answer (score 1):

Existe la posibilidad de darle la propiedad "redondeada", pero solo en el navegador firefox, posiblemente en un futuro se convierta en estándar. Puedes leer más sobre esto aquí: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-outline-radius

Si quieres eliminarlo por estética puedes hacerlo así:

```
.clase_input:focus{
    outline:0px;
}
```